# Can I share a cookie between multiple domains pointing to the same Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have **x.com pointing to apple.y.com**, and separately, also **one.y.com** and **two.y.com**.  I want the user who visits either x.com, one.y.com or two.y.com to share the same sessions.  Is this possible?  If not, what's the best compromise?

Answer (score 1):

`one.y.com` and `two.y.com` can share cookies by setting the cookie domain to `.y.com`.  This will share cookies across all subdomains of `y.com`.

`x.com` cannot share the cookies with `y.com` directly, however.  There is a solution available using redirects, but it's tricky to implement -- http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/article.php/c19417/Sharing-Cookies-Across-Domains.htm (examples are in ASP.net, but you could apply the solution to RoR).

Comment: @MikeAtlas: well, that's the beauty of a site like Stack Overflow.  Instead of down voting because a link is out of date you could spend less than 10 seconds searching Google to find the updated link and edit into the answer.

Comment: Even better would be to just give code examples here in your post, OP could have searched for 10 seconds on google too. Also, do you really think an ASP.NET solution is a good answer for a RoR question?

Comment: @Mike: In the absence of an RoR solution, an ASP.NET that is easy to follow is a good enough answer. I've ported code from languages that I'm unfamiliar with myself, many times and I appreciate a half solution when that's all I can get. I agree, code samples would be better, but not being particularly savvy with RoR, I gave the best answer I could give, which was to describe the solution. The first part of my answer may have solved the OP's question, depending on how x.com -> apple.y.com works. You're welcome to provide your own solution, since this one doesn't meet your standards ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To get applications using the same domain working using the same session cookies, you would configure this in the environment config files.. I do this for some of my applications. This is for Rails 2.3.5 apps, It should be the same for Rails 3, but I am not positive.

First, in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`, make sure that:

```
# ActionController::Base.session_store = :active_record_store
```

is commented out.

Next, all of your applications should use the same key and secret, in the same file, set:

```
ActionController::Base.session = {
  :key         => '_myapp_session',
  :secret      => 'some really long string of hex'
}
```

Finally, configure the environment files to use the same domain:

`config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_controller.session = { 
  :domain => ".rails.local" 
}
```

`config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.action_controller.session = { 
  :domain => ".myapp.com" 
}
```

Comment: This still wouldn't work with x.com and y.com. And why can't you use active_record_store?

Comment: Edited to add that it only works using the same domain. Using active record store may work across apps on different domains, but you'd probably have to use the same database on both applications, which I was never really able to get working once they moved rails 2.3 to rack, which is why I went with sessions cookies with a shared key and secret.

Comment: This doesn't answer any of the OP questions.